# Jenkins: SVN trigger does not correctly build dependencies first

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins

In Jenkins (1.550), I have two maven projects, Model and GUI. The GUI project depends on model:

```
<groupId>com.acme</groupId>
<artifactId>gui</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now, for each project I have Jenkins configured to periodically check SVN and trigger a build, which works just fine.

#### Problem

It only works if only files in one project are changed. Often times, however, a commit will be done on both projects, so let's say these two files will be committed:

```
A /model/Car.java
A /gui/CarDialog.java
```

Now Jenkins will see there is a change in the GUI project, builds it, but fails because `/model/Car.java` is missing (because model hasn't been built yet). Then, some time later, a build in model is triggered (due to the SVN change in model), which builds fine. After that, gui will be built again, this time successfully.

I think this kind of setup is quite common, so I'm pretty sure I've overlooked something, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

#### Workarounds

What didn't work is setting "block while dependencies are being built" on GUI, as at the time the GUI build is building, the Model build might not yet have noticed that there is a change in SVN, thus not building Model.

I've only found workarounds so far, the best working one is as follows:

Configure Model to check for SVN updates every 4 minutes:

```
*/4 * * * *
```

Configure GUI to check for SVN updates every 8 minutes:

```
*/8 * * * *
```

Also, block the GUI build for 60 seconds, block the build if dependencies are being built and start the built after dependencies have finished building.

This has the drawbacks that `*/4` is discouraged (`H/4` should be used) and that it feels like a hack.

Any ideas on how to properly address my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of reading, i found a nice solution:

1. Install the Downstream-Ext Plugin in Jenkins
2. set up your projects: model and gui

   1. Source Code Management with the correct includeRegions, e.g. for model: `model/.*`
   2. Disable "Poll SCM"
3. Create a jenkins build: master

   1. Set the includeRegions that this build fires on any commit: e.g. `.*` or `model/.* ,gui/.*`
   2. Enable "Poll SCM"
   3. Add Post Build Actions: "Build other projects (extended)"

      - Projects to build: `model, gui` (Correct Order is important: upstream,...,downstream)
      - tick "Trigger only if downstream project has SCM changes"
4. Optional: Install dependency-queue-plugin in Jenkins

**Explanation**:

- Project builds are not triggered by SCM changes because of the missing polling
- The master build is triggered every time there is a commit, it doesn't matter which project was committed
- The master build does nothing, except for analyzing the downstream builds in order. If a downstream build has to be triggered because of SCM changes, then it will be queued, otherwise not
- Optional the queue is simplified because of the dependency-queue-plugin